# Error PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed must be of the type array, string given

Tags: php, php7, eloquent

necesito ayuda con un ejercicio que estoy realizando en el cual usando Eloquent trato de recibir los datos de un formulario del archivo addJob.php pero me genera el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::__construct() must be of the type array, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio\app\Models\Job.php on line 13 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php:166 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio\app\Models\Job.php(13): Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model->__construct('t1', 'd1') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio\addJob.php(39): App\Models\Job->__construct('t1', 'd1', '3') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\portafolio\vendor\illuminate\database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 166

Código ->addJob.php

```
    <?php
//autoload composer
require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

//iluminate

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
use App\Models\BaseElement;
use App\Models\Job;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection([
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => 'localhost',
    'port'      => '3307',
    'database'  => 'portafolio',
    'username'  => 'root',
    'password'  => '',
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
]);

// Make this Capsule instance available globally via static methods... (optional)
$capsule->setAsGlobal(); //Maneja todo de manera Global

// Setup the Eloquent ORM... (optional; unless you've used setEventDispatcher())
$capsule->bootEloquent(); //inicializa el ORM



//variable superglobales, diferentes tipos de variables que nos permiten acceder a distintas partes de la app
var_dump($_GET); //recibe un arreglo de x elemntos y estos son visibles en la url
var_dump($_POST); //con post no se ve en la url, asi se recibe la información de method="post"

//nueva instancia de jobs para poder usar la tabla jobs mediante iluminate
if(!empty($_POST)){
    $job = new Job($_POST['Title'],$_POST['Description'],$_POST['Months']);
    $job->save();
}

var_dump($job->months);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Add Job</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Job</h1>
    <form action="addJob.php" method="post"> <!-- con method="post" se envian los datos sin mostrarse en la url -->
        <label>Title: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Title"/> <br>
        <label>Description: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Description"/> <br />
        <label>Months: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Months"/> <br />
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Código ->clase Job.php

```
<?php
namespaceApp\Models;
useApp\Models\BaseElement;

//iluminate
useIlluminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

classJobextendsModel{
    protected $months;
    protected $table = 'jobs';

    publicfunction__construct($title,$description,$months){
        parent::__construct($title,$description);
        $this->months = $months;
    }

  publicfunctionprintElement($element){
        echo'<li class="work-position">'; 
        echo'<h3>' .$element->title . '</h3>';
        echo'<p>' .$element->description . '</p>';
        echo'<p>'.$element->getDurationAsString() . '</p>';
        echo'<strong>Achievements:</strong>';
        echo'<ul>';
        echo' <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 80% consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>';
        echo' <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 80% consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>';
        echo' <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 80% consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>';
        echo'</ul>';
    }

    publicfunctiongetDurationAsString(){
        $years = floor($this->months / 12);
        $extraMonths = $this->months % 12;
        if($years < 1){
            $duracion = "months: $this->months";
        } elseif($years >= 1and $this->months >= 1){
            $duracion = "years: $years months: $extraMonths";
        }else{
            $duracion = "years: $years";
        }
        return $duracion;
    }

}
```

Código-> clase BaseElement.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class BaseElement{
        protected $title;
        protected $description;

        public function __construct($title,$description){
            $this->title = $title;
            $this->description = $description;
        }

        public function printElement($element){

        }




}
```

He probado también eliminar el constructor de la clase Job y pasar el parametro así: $job->months ) $_POST['Months']; pasa el formulario y no da error pero no se guarda en la base de datos. Agradecería mucho su retroalimentación.

Comment: La clase job hereda de model, no de baseElement... Puedes mostrar el código de la clase model?

Comment: Te faltan espacios en declaraciones de clase `classJobextendsModel` y métodos `publicfunction__construct(`

Comment: @Triby Si es una error, cuando copie el código al realizar la pregunta pero en el editor de texto si esta correctamente separado.

Comment: @Jakala El archivo Model.php es un modelo de Eloquent y es un archivo super largo, aqui anexo solo la función que se encuentra en la linea 166 donde refleja el error `    public function __construct(array $attributes = [])
    {
        $this->bootIfNotBooted();

        $this->initializeTraits();

        $this->syncOriginal();

        $this->fill($attributes);
    }`

Comment: pues ya lo estas diciendo tu. Como puedes ver, en tu Job, que heredas de Model, llamas en el constructor al parent. Ese parent es Model.php de eloquent, y requiere un array como primer parametro. Pienso que quizas te has equivocado y no debes heredar de model, sino de tu baseElement... no? cambia `classJobextendsModel{` por `class Job extends baseElement{`

Comment: @Jakala Es que ya probe heredar Model a BaseElement y luego heredar Base a la clase Job pero al momento de enviar los datos del formulario no se porque llegan vacios, es decir se crea el registro pero no se guarda nada. La unica forma de que funcione correctamente es que agregue el atributo months desde el constructor de BaseElement pero no quiero hacerlo porque hay otra clase que hereda de BaseElement que no usa el atributo months.

Comment: Logre hacer que funcionara eliminando el constructor de la clase Job y asignando los valores a los atributos de la siguiente manera ```$job = new Job();
    $job->title = $_POST['Title'];
    $job->description = $_POST['Description'];
    $job->months = $_POST['Months']; ```  Creo que no es ideal pero almacena los valores correctamente.

Comment: Sin embargo al hacer esto se almacena los datos en la base, pero al momento de mostrarlos con la función printElement() de clase Job me refleja que el atributo months esta como NULL.